# Many to Many saving data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have the following schema

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('userName')->default('');
    $table->string('userEmail')->default('');
    $table->tinyInteger('active')->default(1);
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('user_groups', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('groupName')->default('');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('users_user_groups', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->integer('userId')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('userId')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('groupId')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('groupId')->references('id')->on('user_groups')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Essentially, a User can be apart of many Groups, and a Group can have many Users.

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'users_user_groups')->withPivot('userId', 'groupId');
    }
}

class Group extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_groups';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'users_user_groups')->withPivot('userId', 'groupId');
    }
}
```

I think the Models are ok.  I then have an updateUsers function in my controller

```
public function updateUsers()
{
    $users = Helper::returnUsersFromLdap();

    DB::table('users')->update(array('active' => false));
    foreach($users as $userName => $userData) {
        $user = User::firstOrNew(['userName' => $userName]);

        foreach ($userData as $userEmail => $userDepartment) {

            $user->userEmail = $userEmail;
            $user->active = true;

            $userGroups = Helper::returnGroupsFromLdap($userEmail);

            foreach($userGroups as $group) {
                $user->groups()->sync($group);
            }
        }
        $user->save();
    }

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Users updated');
    Session::flash('flash_type', 'alert-success');
    return Redirect::route('users.index');
}
```

I essentially get a user list from Active directory, loop this, and add the my users table.  For each user, I call returnGroupsFromLdap passing the users email as a parameter.  For each user, this will return the groups that user is in like so

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "Group1"
  1 => "Group2"
  2 => "Group3"
]
```

My question is how can I link the user groups to a user?  So I loop each group and then add it to my user_groups table?  But then where do I populate the pivot table I created?

Any advice on this matter appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you should use `sync()` method. `$user->groups()->sync($userGroups);`

Comment: Edit `
    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'users_user_groups', 'userId', 'userGroupsId');
    }`

Comment: Many thanks - I have updated the original post with some changes I made.  I have also tried it using withPivot.  The error I am getting is Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'group_id' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sync method to update the user groups from the user model:

```
$user->groups()->sync([1, 2, 3]);
```

Where `[1, 2, 3]` is an array with group ids. Laravel will know to save this relation in the table that you specified in the belongsToMany() relatiotnship in the model.

But you might have to specify the column names because by default Laravel uses another naming convention:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'users_user_groups')->withPivot('userId', 'userGroupsId');
```

Check the documentation for more details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Many thanks - I have updated the original post with some changes I made.  I have also tried it using withPivot.  The error I am getting is Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'group_id' in 'field list'

Comment: You need to specify the names of the columns, because like I said Laravel uses another naming convention, which is different than your column names.

Comment: Am I not defining the names of my columns though within the Models using the third and fourth parameters?  I have also done it withPivot and I get the same error

Comment: If you're still getting "Unknown column 'group_id' in 'field list'" it means that you have to specify the column name to 'userGroupsId'.

Comment: I have updated the post again to what you suggested.  For some reason though I still get the same error.  Do I need the pivot on both models?

Comment: Yes, you should specify the column names on both models.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users_user_groups', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('userId')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('userGroupsId')->unsigned();
    });

    Schema::table('users_user_groups', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('userId')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('userGroupsId')->references('id')->on('user_groups');
    });
}
```

Comment: Is that not what I have, just split across two Schemas?

Comment: You should use `Schema::create() {}` first and  `Schema::table(){}` add foreign key.

Comment: doesnt seem to make a difference, still getting same error mentioned above